# Passing parameters using the PUT method

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I defined an endpoint with the following methods:

```java
@ApiMethod(name = "update", path = "properties/{id}", httpMethod = HttpMethod.PUT)
public void update(@Named("id") Long id, RealEstatePropertyAPI propertyAPI,
        User user) {
```

On the client side I tried several calls but none of them populates the `propertyAPI` object on the server side. The instance is created with all fields set to `null` except the `id`.

```js
        var jsonId = { 'id': '11'};
        var x = {"name": "Test","address": { "street": "White House"}};
        gapi.client.realestate.update(jsonId, x).execute(function(resp) {
            console.log('PropertyEdited');
            console.log(resp);
        });
```

Or

```js
        var jsonId = { 'id': '11'};
        var x = {"name": "Test","address": { "street": "White House"}};
        gapi.client.realestate.update(jsonId, {'resource' : x}).execute(function(resp) {
            console.log('PropertyEdited');
            console.log(resp);
        });
```

The Java classes:

```java
public class RealEstatePropertyAPI {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private AddressAPI address;

    public RealEstatePropertyAPI() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public AddressAPI getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(AddressAPI address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}

public class AddressAPI {

    private Long id;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;
    private String country;

    public AddressAPI() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually sure about about this, but you can try to pass all the parameters within a single object, I mean wrap the parameters with brackets `{ }`, like this:

```
//var jsonId = { 'id': '11'};
var x = {"name": "Test","address": { "street": "White House"}};
gapi.client.realestate.update({'id': '11', 'resource' : x}).execute(function(resp) {
    console.log('PropertyEdited');
    console.log(resp);
});
```

Because in fact in both your requests you're sending 2 objects... 
And I think you have to use `'resource'` for the parameters in the POST data as in your second option...

Comment: `{{ "id": "11" }, {"resource" : {"name": "Test","address": { "street": "White House"}}}}` is not a valid `JSON` String. I tested it with http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: @Sydney you're indeed right! I edited the answer... the point is to send a single object as the parameter...

Comment: I tried your `JSON` string and still have the same problem, `id` is populated with `11` but not the `propertyAPI` object is created but not populated. Sounds like a bug?